# Duplicating a row in a data-frame n number of times with positional spec

Tags: r, dataframe

Sample df:

```
iris_subset <- iris[1:5, ]

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

I'm looking for the best solution where I can duplicate a specific row, n number of times, with the opportunity to state positionally where to insert the duplicate rows.

For example, I want to duplicate row 2 two times, after the original row.

Desired output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
4          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
5          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
7          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Sloppily, I can do something like:

```
iris_subset <- rbind(iris_subset, iris[2,], iris[2,])
iris_subset <- iris_subset[c(1:2, 6:7, 3:5),]
row.names(iris_subset) <- 1:nrow(iris_subset)
```

But if I want to functionalise this, I need a better way of repeating the row I want duplicated than manually passing in additional arguments n times in `rbind` or other alternatives, which is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row_ind = 2
repeat_n = 3
place_at_row = 3
inds = append(x = 1:NROW(iris_subset),
          values = rep(row_ind, repeat_n),
          after = place_at_row - 1)
iris_subset[inds,]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2.1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2.2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2.3          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Ultimately preferred this solution as less dependency + 20x quicker through microbenchmark.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `add_row` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
add_row(iris_subset, !!! as.list(iris_subset[rep(2, each = 3),]), .after = 2)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#4          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#5          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#7          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#8          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```